# Real and Imaginary parts of Lebesgue integral in L1 (folland's real analysis)

Tags: measure-theory, complex-numbers, lebesgue-integral

I am working through Folland's Real Analysis and have a question about a proposition on functions in L1. Prop (2.22) states:

given $f \in L^1$, then $|\int f| \leq \int|f|$

In the proof, for when f is complex valued, they define

$ \alpha = sgn(\int f)$ and state that $\int \alpha f$ is real. I am unsure about how this statement is true. My understanding is that if $f$ is complex, then $\int f$ is the supremum of simple functions with complex coefficients,

i.e. $a_j \in \mathbb{C}$, and

$\int f = sup\{\int \phi\::\: 0 \leq \phi \leq f,\: \phi\:simple \}$ where

$\int \phi = \sum a_j \mu(E_j)$

Wouldn't this make the integral complex?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folland is using the complex sign, defined by $sgn(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$

$\alpha = \frac{\overline{\int f}}{|\int f|}$, so $\alpha \int f$ is real.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I am following correctly, then alpha is the signum of the complex conjugate of the integral of f, and hence when alpha is multiplied by f (or its integral) the result is a real number (basically what you and Ittay are both saying). This is because when (a+bi)*(a-bi) is multiplied out, the Imaginary part is cancelled and i is squared?

Comment: Correct.  Note that $\alpha * f$ is not a real-valued function, but $\alpha * \int f$ is a real number.  For any complex number $z$, we have $z\overline{z} = |z|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that for Lebesgue integrable functions, $\int c\cdot f=c\cdot \int f$. Now, $\alpha$ is chosen so that $\alpha \cdot \int f$ is real, and since $\int \alpha f=\alpha \int f$ it follows that $\int \alpha f$ is real.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I think this has me on the right track. As always I need to work on being more careful with definitions and notation!

Comment: you are welcome.